# Characterization of consistent methods for linear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let us consider an invertible matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and let $b\in \mathbb C^n$. Let $B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $c\in\mathbb C^n$ and suppose

$$x_{k+1}=B\cdot x_k+c\quad (k\in\mathbb N)$$
are the iterations of a numerical method for solving $$A\cdot x=b.$$ Let us say the method is **consistent** if whenever $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges, it follows

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k=A^{-1}\cdot b.$$

I'd like to prove the method is consistent if and only if:

$a)$ $I-B$ is invertible, where $I\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is the identity;

$b)$ $(I-B)^{-1}\cdot c =A^{-1}\cdot b$.

I was able to show the implication $(\Rightarrow)$  as follows

Suppose that  $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges, let us say,
\begin{align*}
    y=\lim_{k\to \infty}x_k. 
\end{align*}
Noticing that
\begin{align*}
    x_{k+1}-x&= B\cdot x_k+c-x\\
    &=B\cdot x_k+c-B\cdot x-(I-B)\cdot x\\
    &=B\cdot (x_k-x)+c-(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b. 
\end{align*}
it follows
\begin{align*}
    y-x&=\lim_{k\to \infty}(x_{k+1}-x)\\
    &=\lim_{k\to \infty}(B\cdot (x_k-x)+c-(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b)\\
    &=B\cdot (y-x)+c-(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b
\end{align*}
and, therefore,
\begin{align*}
    (I-B)\cdot (y-x)=c-(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b. 
\end{align*}
If $I-B$ is invertible and $(I-B)^{-1}\cdot c=A^{-1}\cdot b$, it follows
\begin{align*}
    y-x&= (I-B)^{-1}\cdot (I-B)\cdot (y-x)\\
    &=(I-B)^{-1}\cdot c-(I-B)^{-1}\cdot (I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b\\ 
    &=A^{-1}\cdot b-A^{-1}\cdot b\\ 
    &=0
\end{align*}
so that $y=x=A^{-1}\cdot b$, showing the method is consistent.

How to show the converse?

I thought of the following: If the method is consistent then $y=A^{-1}\cdot b=x$, so
\begin{align*}
  (I-B)\cdot (y-x)=c-(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b
\end{align*}
implies
\begin{align*}
(I-B)\cdot A^{-1}\cdot b=c. 
\end{align*}
This shows $(I-B)\cdot x=c$ has solution $x=A^{-1}\cdot b$. If I could show this solution is unique it would follow $(I-B)$ is invertible and $(I-B)^{-1}\cdot c=A^{-1}\cdot b$. But I wasn't able to show $x=A^{-1}\cdot b$ was the unique solution to $(I-B)\cdot x=c$.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose there is a $u \ne x$ such that $(I-B)u = c$. What happens when you let $x_0 = u$?

Comment: Well, that would produce a constant sequence $x_k=u$. But I can't change the sequence and I don't have the hypothesis the iterations converge for any given $x_0\in \mathbb C^n$.

Comment: There is nothing in your requirements about what value $\{x_k\}_k$ starts with. I interpret that definition of "consistent" to mean that *whatever* the starting value, if the sequence converges, it converges to $A^{-1}b$. That means $u$ has to be $A^{-1}b$, which is exactly what you need. I suggest you check your sources about the intended meaning.

Comment: That is the point, I can finish the proof using your suggestion under the hypothesis that it does not depend on the starting value. Maybe I misunderstood the concept of consistency given in my reference. Thanks again!